# Duplicating table data and keeping one value unique

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to duplicate existing table data while keeping values of specific column unique.
The idea I decided to use:

1. Create TempTable with all columns of necessary type MyActualTable has;
2. Calculate @MAX_KEY value from MyActualTable (from a column where I need to keep values unique);
3. Insert data from TempTable back into MyActualTable while adding @MAX_KEY to every KEY from TempTable.

In theory it would allow to keep the KEY column values unique:

```
CREATE PROC CopyData
AS

/*Creates TempTable with columns as in MyActualTable*/
select top 0 *
into #TempTable
from MyActualTable

DECLARE @MAX_KEY INT

/*Selects max value from KEY column of MyActualTable*/
SELECT TOP 1 @MAX_KEY=KEY
FROM MyActualTable
ORDER BY KEY DESC


INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT * FROM MyActualTable

/*Suppusedly should add @MAX_KEY value to every inserted KEY value*/
INSERT INTO MyActualTable SELECT @MAX_KEY+KEY
,[Column1]
,[Column2]
FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable

GO
```

Data from MyActualTable is inserted into TempTable alright, but no new rows are inserted back into MyActualTable, no errors.

I'm not very experienced in SQL, so if you have another solution instead of this one - please share with me.

Comment: Why the top 0 to create the table then and insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need any temp table

```
SELECT @MAX_KEY= MAX(KEY) FROM MyActualTable

INSERT INTO MyActualTable 
SELECT @MAX_KEY+KEY
  ,[Column1]
  ,[Column2]
FROM MyActualTable
```